# Issue : Connecting using OAuth to Jawbone from android app

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, jawbone

We are using Jawbone API to pull data tracked using jawbone devices.
Our users are successfully able to sign in when they access Jawbone sign in page during OAuth process from our website.

However, they are not able to sign in when they access jawbone authentication page from our android app during OAuth process. This authentication page is launched in webview on andriod.
On log in page after entering correct credentials and clicking on Sign In button does nothing. The page even does not display whether credentials were correct or not.

Is the OAuth authentication user agent (web/app) dependent?

We have started facing this issue just recently and before it used to work perfectly.

Comment: Can you see the HTTP status of the sign in request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jawbone's OAuth2 flow operates through web login and approval pages, then issues a redirect callback to your server. Jawbone has several partners who do this within their Android apps.

It sounds like your app is not handling the callback half of the OAuth2 flow correctly, but it's hard to say based on this description.

Have you reviewed the [Authentication documentation](https://jawbone.com/up/developer/authentication)?

Also, consider [Jawbone's Android SDK](https://github.com/Jawbone/UPPlatform_Android_SDK/).